# Any good tutorials for the open source 3d frameworks like cocos3d?

Tags: iphone, cocos3d

Is there any good tutorial for the 3d game free frameworks like cocos3d? the isgl3d has more detailed tutorials and samples than cocos3d, is there any good stuff for either?

Thanks,

PS. even the StackOverflow has too many unanswered question under the cocos3d tag.

Comment: Like you, I started out in Cocos3d, but jumped to [Unity](http://unity3d.com/). I highly recommend using Unity as it supports both iOS and Android (and soon, the Windows 8 mobile platform). I managed to get it when they were giving their basic licenses away fro free, so might be worth checking?

Answer (score 0):

Check below link it may be useful 
http://mashable.com/2010/08/11/cross-platform-mobile-development-tools/

Comment: Sorry, did not see there any answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Bucky's tutorials will help you.

> http://thenewboston.org/tutorials.php